# Need to update Mysql periodically from Oracle

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I have a user table in Mysql. And this table is copied from another DB(Oracle).

Of course they have totally same table. And it needs to be updated once a day.(Mysql ← Oracle)

Is it possible to access Oracle and retrieve data within MYsql? I mean things like procedure.

([It seems possible between Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html))

Or do I have to find other way?

Comment: No, at least not easily using the standard set of tools - but if you told us what OS and what programming / scripting tools you have available then maybe we could give a more helpful suggestion

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to give a details. Os is Win Server 2003 and language is ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool in dbForge Studio for MySQL.

- Start Data Import
- Check ODBC format, specify its options and select table to import from
- Specify mapping and other options
- Select Append, Update or Append/Update import mode.

Also, you can run this tool in command line mode. Save data import template file and run it in command line mode once a day.

Comment: Yes, you may use windows scheduler.